# Exclude a checkbox from .click() of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tryin to make a div 'active' by clicking on it using jquery. But inside the div, there is a checkbox. I want the div to become active whenever i click anywher inside the div except the checkbox. I have done that, but the checkbox is now not responsding to click events (ie it's not getting checked/unchecked when i click on it).

http://jsfiddle.net/U7VmV/3/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.c-video').click(function(){
        $('.c-video').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
}).children().find('label').click(function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [event.stoppropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
}).find('label').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cB7bR/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the propagation of the event, when you `return false` it prevents the event propagation but it will also prevents the default action of the click event that is checking/unchecking the checkbox.

So instead or returning false call [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) in the event object

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.c-video').click(function(){
        $('.c-video').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
}).children().find('label').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A8LeH/)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to check clicked event target:

```
var $cVideo = $('.c-video').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName != 'INPUT' && e.target.tagName != 'LABEL') {
        $cVideo.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7VmV/4/